# Add option for BarButtonItem not appearing in Visual Studio form Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Sometimes when I open my Visual Studio form designer, I see the [Add] text to create a new BarButtonItem, other times I don't. This has led me to search for a way to create a new button several times now. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Are you using [Visual Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx1155fz.aspx)? That is - having a base form that all other forms inherit from.

Comment: No Visual Inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to right click your bar manager, and check the **Show DesignTime Enhancements**.
Here is [a link](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5350) that may help.

Comment: Yes, un-checking and checking that brought it back, awesome, thank you.